# Full height sidebar over content inside a wrapper

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project using Bootstrap 3 where I need to place a sidebar over the sections with content, but respecting the width of the `.container` wrapper. The sidebar must fill the full page height and be scrollable.

This JSFiddle (link in comments because I can't post more than 2 links yet) shows the structure I have, with their styles. You can see the issue by playing with the height of the HTML frame on JSFiddle, making it smaller than the page height.

To better illustrate, these images show the sidebar in blue, filling all the page height, in all cases:

- [Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVPkF.png): the sections are taller than the viewport; the sidebar follows the body height
- [Case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VehOf.png): the sections doesn't fill all the page, but the sidebar does

Note: it's important that the sidebar follows the width of `.container`. The content below doesn't, it is full width and partially visible.

Bonus: in Case 2, the section should be full height as well

I tried to give the more details I could, but I can provide any additional info.

I know it's possible through script, but I'd prefer using just CSS

Comment: JSFiddle illustrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/1e9ntthk/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to help with out more details. But I went ahead and made this fiddle that has a 100% height colored background using your markup: https://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/8xdfosf6/

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
  background: #bada55;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.sections {
  background-color: #b000b5;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Steve! Sadly, this is not the solution for my problem. I expanded your JSFiddle to better represent the case. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/1e9ntthk/1/